# How can I trigger an automatic click to an alert btn ok to continue loading the target url?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, alert

I'm using cheerio to **scrape** a web eCommerce pages, but the problem the page is blocking in an alert question if I click OK manually it pass well , how can I do that click automatically when the alert shown.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you cant with cheerio.
https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio/issues/1226

Try to look projects like PhantomJS / JSDom or Selenium for browser automation and browser testing.